# Manage race condition with Spring Cassandra counters

Tags: spring, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a Cassandra table [User] with a "counter" column called count. The table schema is as follows:

```
@Builder
@Table(value = "User")
public class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  private String id;

  @Getter
  @Column("count")
  @CassandraType(type= CassandraType.Name.COUNTER)
  private long count;
}
```

The "count" column will be accessed and updated by multiple servers and in a **concurrent** fashion. Hence, I have a requirement to avoid race conditions.

As per the solution suggested here: [Race conditions with Cassandra Counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794343/race-conditions-with-cassandra-counters/53798392#53798392) we will have to maintain **"SERIAL"** consistency with counters to make our query linearizable.

Accordingly, as per [spring-data-cassandra set consistency level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921062/spring-data-cassandra-set-consistency-level/47016324#47016324) I have created my Repository class as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<UserEntity, String> {
    @Query("UPDATE User SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = ?0")
    @Consistency(DefaultConsistencyLevel.SERIAL)
    Flux<UserEntity> incrementCount(String id);
}
```

But, with this approach, I observe the following exception

```
CQL [UPDATE User SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = ?]; Counter operations are inherently non-serializable
```

What is the right way to ensure there are no race conditions and consistency is maintained with Cassandra counters?